# Shall I put the use VERSION at the top of my file

Tags: perl

I've seen that Perl allows you to put a `use VERSION` statement at the top of the file, e.g.

```
use v5.16.3;
```

which results in a compiler error if the current version of the interpreter is smaller.

Is it good practice to specify the version number?

Comment: Only if you depend on some feature which can't be found in minor versions.

Comment: See also [Syntax::Construct](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Construct) (blatant self promotion).

Comment: When your script's behaviour depends on some language features (or bug fix) added in a release, you should include the version ,for example using the say, state function added in 5.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, you should `use VERSION;` only if your scripts depend on some language features or bug fixes which cannot be found in minor versions. For example using `say`, which is added in Perl 5.10.

Also, you can use [`Syntax::Construct`](http://search.cpan.org/~choroba/Syntax-Construct-0.08/lib/Syntax/Construct.pm) to state which non-feature constructs you want to use in your code.

Comment: These days most people would find it pretty challenging to write Perl code that will run unmodified on Perl 5.005. (no Unicode, no 3-argument `open`, no `use warnings`, no weak references, no `our` variables, weirdly behaving `qw()`, etc.) Chances are that any code you write is going to rely on *some* vaguely modern Perl features. I like to always start a file with `use VERSION` as a declaration of intent. It acts as a reminder for me - "oh yes, I can't use `//` because I want to support Perl 5.8.3".

Comment: @tobyink This is a community wiki answer, you could improve it by editing it directly.